# Play upgrade to 2.3.8 fails scala tests that use wiremock

Tags: scala, unit-testing, playframework, wiremock

I recently updated my Play Scala project to 2.3.8 with Slick etc.

From that time onwards, my unit tests which use Wiremock keeps on failing.

The error looks:

```
  The future returned an exception of type: java.lang.RuntimeException, with message: There is no started application.
```

Would appreciate in case of any help/suggestions?

```
class BlahTest extends FunSuite
  with MockitoSugar with ScalaFutures
  with SpanSugar with BeforeAndAfter with BeforeAndAfterAll {

val wiremock = new WireMockServer(wireMockConfig().port(1234)
  .fileSource(new SingleRootFileSource("test/resources")))

override protected def beforeAll() = wiremock.start()

override protected def afterAll() = wiremock.stop()

before {
  Mockito.reset(mockLogger)
  configureFor("localhost", 1234)
  stubFor(post(urlMatching("/somepath"))
    .willReturn(aResponse()
    .withStatus(200)))
}

after {
  WireMock.reset()
}

test("Some test") {
  val f = someObject.method(param1, param2)
  whenReady(f, timeout(WiremockTimeout milliseconds)) { answer =>
    // verify
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your test starts up a [FakeApplication](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.8/api/scala/index.html#play.api.test.FakeApplication) first. One way of doing this is to make your test class extends [WithApplication](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.8/api/scala/index.html#play.api.test.WithApplication).

Comment: Actually, I have solved that by implementing my own FakeApplication where I set my own variables etc.